# How do I make Python to accept only specific entries for a list which is user prompted.

Tags: python, list, data-manipulation

How do I make Python to accept only specific entries for a list which is user prompted. For example: I want my list to accept only the grades: A, B, C, D, E, F. And nothing else.

Comment: Write a function that takes user input and complains when the input is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get on the right track by starting with a function that returns a Boolean value depending on whether the provided input is in some collection of valid inputs:

```
def is_valid_option(option):
  valid_options = ['A', 'B', 'C']
  if option in valid_options:
    return True
  return False
```

You can then check if `is_valid_option(some_input)`